# Identify the smoothing filter from boundary pattern

Tags: filter-design, smoothing

I have a collection of discrete timeseries, which has already been smoothed temporally. However, the smoothing operation does not consider the boudary properly, and results in obvious distortion. I seek to find the correct smooth algorithm, then try to compensate it at the boundary in someway. **Note that the original timeseries are available in very limited amount, and the majority of samples have only smoothed version. Therefore, what I seek is a way to identify then compensate. Using a better smoothing technique on the original series to avoid the boundary effects in the first place is not applicable to my context.**

Since the data itself is somewhat confidential, I made a simple sketch to show the idea.
[image: Figure]
In the figure, blue line is the smoothed timeseries, orange line is the original timeseries, and black line is the error between smoothed and original value.

1D gaussian filter could produce similar effect at the boundary (the negative error part), but could not explain the positive error part.

Comment: Nope. I only have a collection of timeseries, but I have made sure that almost all series suit the pattern above.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to identify the (black box) filter kernel so as to negate its effect, before applying your own smoothing filter? If so, is this not a deconvolution problem?

Comment: One issue with identifying a filter from its edge behaviour is that it might have separate logic to handle edges, possibly nonlinear/space-variant. Meaning that a simple step-response might not describe the full behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to ensure that the initial conditions for the filtering operation are non-zero and remove the artifacts.  However, I'm not sure how to do that with the end effects.

Another approach to remove boundary effects in image processing is to tile the data one after the other, but flipping it at each boundary.

[image: Attempt to fix the problem.]

If I do that with some synthesized data, then I get the red dots above, which seem to be nicely distributed around zero.

The trick here is to detrend the data first, and then add the estimated trend back in after filtering / smoothing.

---

#### Code Below

```matlab
% 91553
m = 2.333;
c = 1.1180;
N = 1000;
n = 0:N-1;

y = m*n + c + randn(1,N)/2;
z = filter(ones(1,10)/10,1,y);

coefs = polyfit(n, y, 1);
yy = detrend(y);
z2 = filter(ones(1,10)/10,1,[flip(yy),yy,flip(yy)]);
zz = z2(N + n) + coefs(2) +coefs(1)*n;

subplot(211)
plot(n,y)
hold on;
plot(n,z);
plot(n,zz);
hold off;

subplot(212);
plot(n,y-z);
hold on;
plot(n,y-zz,'r.');
hold off;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am also aware of quite a few ways to avoid boundary effects, but what I seek is a some-what different problem. I've updated my question above to reflect this. Sorry for the inclarity.

Comment: @Vapor Ok! Thanks for the update. I’m a little confused: what are you trying to identify? The filter? Or the original data? Or something else?